DC 5V Booster module not working when load connected
Circuit 1 AA battery (1.5v) connected to step up module (5v) can power a 5V DC cooling fan standard
Circuit 2 if a DC centrifugal/ radial 5V cooling fan is connected then its not working.
I tried 2 AA batteries (3V) then 3 AA batteries (4.5v) with module but still not working.
Circuit 3 The 3 AA batteries (4.5v) when directly connected to DC radial fan 4020 then it works.
Circuit 4 The DC radial fan works fine with 5V mobile charger.
How can i make circuit 2 work i.e. with one AA battery & 5v DC module





What kind of stepping converter and fan are these? The converter can only power 40mA-100 mA under 5V with input of 1.5 V. https://www.amazon.com/Comidox-Module-Voltage-Converter-0-9-5V/dp/B07L76KLRY

My guess is that the centrifugal blower has a much higher startup current than the standard fan, and this is causing the converter to shut down.

"better" choice https://www.amazon.com/Teyleten-Robot-0-9V-5V-Converter-Voltage/dp/B0CLTXY9MX/ref=sr_1_16?crid=2PA34MAQM03IX&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.S6wPEdk6hHssQPWE1ojRKNcYhGIgP7rfddJwruVLfMt8ZQX_ekylGDr20vn8FCy7fbYskP6BqpleiwXxT5djbTfnlyfoIT_nZ1hp4VifyZOAeVahof0c2W_6Planp90U7vgflBtmwvYMmK1ad74R5j-IEaOhwjMUek8dnYg-qapT66B_cBRQI6yuHh33oN8Q3RCjIWzQJrqqc4ktEqi0vfBsnbFXtHYagiYWtSgbxVE.C4-49XppUlGqrTOayX4Rd2ZUtamMDvi-7WgmtzfD_6E&dib_tag=se&keywords=step+up+booster+converter+from+1.5v+to+5v+300mA+output&qid=1727890815&sprefix=step+up+booster+converter+from+1.5v+to+5v+300ma+output%2Caps%2C145&sr=8-16

Or this one with 2V minimum ? https://www.amazon.com/Eiechip-Voltage-Regulator-Converter-Module/dp/B07RNBJK5F/ref=pd_rhf_dp_s_pd_sbs_rvi_d_sccl_2_1/141-3241689-4307018?pd_rd_w=F1qEY&content-id=amzn1.sym.46e2be74-be72-4d3f-86e1-1de279690c4e&pf_rd_p=46e2be74-be72-4d3f-86e1-1de279690c4e&pf_rd_r=W43M31YEC2AMS5P7NR6A&pd_rd_wg=a0Ikk&pd_rd_r=eb9b90cc-41eb-4b38-9242-d4226f54c738&pd_rd_i=B07RNBJK5F&psc=1

@AnalogKid Yes, i think so but how to make it work?  The DC radial fan with mobile charger OR 3 AA batteries (4.5v) shows 130mA BUT with 5v step up module it just jerks and does not spin. While at that moment of minor spin the current reading shows 770mA.

@Antonio51 Better i go with 5v battery

to make it work use a different battery or a different boost module
